# Is it possible to swipe from an TabBarView content area to an adjacent PageView page?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to place a tabs inside a horizontal PageView and be able to swipe out of the tabs. Within the content area, I can swipe into the tabs from a page, but not out of the tabs to another page. If I swipe on the TabBar, then I can get out of the tabs and go to the adjacent page.

Is there a way to allow me to swipe from a TabView content area and have it move to the adjacent PageView page?

Here is my test code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Page 1'),),
          body: Center(child: Text('hi'),),
        ),
        DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(widget.title),
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Page 3'),),
          body: Center(child: Text('bye'),),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you're looking for. Do you have some sort of mock?

Comment: The second page in the PageView has 3 tabs. If on the first tab and I swipe left to right, I'd like to swipe to Page 1. If on the third tab and I swipe right to left, I'd like to swipe to Page 3.

Comment: I think I got it. I've posted an answer.

Comment: @jibbers42 Did you manage to solve this? I recently asked one very similar question, but got no satisfatory answer yet...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60642631/how-to-merge-scrolls-on-a-tabbarview-inside-a-pageview

Comment: @MateusFelipe Unfortunately no... I'll try to remember to update this issue if I come across a solution.

Comment: I have updated my answer in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60712386/3043944).. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I believe I got the idea of what you're looking for. For this, I suggest using something like a `NotificationListener` in your widget tree that will catch the `OverscrollNotification` and you can either scroll to left or right, depending of the overscroll side (less than 0 for left, over 0 for right).

I made it animate linearly (250 ms) for each side, but you can tweak it to your needs.

[image: example]

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  Example({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(child: Text('Page 1')),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TabPageSelector(controller: _tabController),
              Text('Page 2'),
              NotificationListener(
                onNotification: (overscroll) {
                  if (overscroll is OverscrollNotification && overscroll.overscroll != 0 && overscroll.dragDetails != null) {
                    _pageController.animateToPage(overscroll.overscroll < 0 ? 0 : 2,
                        curve: Curves.ease, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250));
                  }
                  return true;
                },
                child: Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Center(child: Text('Tab 1')),
                      Center(child: Text('Tab 2')),
                      Center(child: Text('Tab 3')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Center(child: Text('Page 3')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a cool solution, but I'd really like it to look/feel like other tab/page swipes if possible. For example, I would like to be able to leave my finger on the screen and drag from Tab3 to Page3 and see it it partially pull in like normal, but then be able to change my mind and drag the other way back to Tab3 to cancel the change. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is, but it's more complex as you need to handle the gesture offsets. For that particular solution, I'd suggest you to use two nested `TabBarView` and display the `TabPageSelector` only in the second page (where you have the second `TabBarView` with 3 tabs). This way, you should achieve what you're looking for with ease.

Comment: I tried to nest a `TabBarView` inside another `TabBarView`, but the result was the same. The inner `TabBarView` has a "barrier" keeping me from swiping out.

Answer (score -2):

Tabbar has a property called onTap. In onTap(), you can get the index and handle your pageview's content. Example:

```
    TabBar(
          onTap: (int tabIndex) {
// you can perform any action here using index
       })
```

Comment: I'd like the swipe to be natural and flowing, similar to how built in PageView or TabBarView swiping looks and feels.