# How to "merge" scrolls on a TabBarView inside a PageView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app that uses a PageView on its main page. Today, I got assigned to insert a TabBarView in one of these pages. The problem is that when I scroll the between the tabs when in the last tab, scrolling to the left won't scroll the PageView.

I need a way to make the scroll of page view scroll when at the start or end of the tabbarview.

I found a question with the inverted problem: [flutter PageView inside TabBarView: scrolling to next tab at the end of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57059844/flutter-pageview-inside-tabbarview-scrolling-to-next-tab-at-the-end-of-page)

However, the method stated there is not suitable to my issue.

I made a minimal example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        title: 'TabBarView inside PageView',
        home: MyHomePage(),
      );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('TabBarView inside PageView'),
        ),
        body: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(color: Colors.red),
            GreenShades(),
            Container(color: Colors.yellow),
          ],
        ),
      );
}

class GreenShades extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GreenShadesState createState() => _GreenShadesState();
}

class _GreenShadesState extends State<GreenShades>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    this._tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TabBar(
            labelColor: Colors.green,
            indicatorColor: Colors.green,
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: <Tab>[
              const Tab(text: "Dark"),
              const Tab(text: "Normal"),
              const Tab(text: "Light"),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(color: Colors.green[800]),
                Container(color: Colors.green),
                Container(color: Colors.green[200]),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Note that, in this MRE, it's possible to reach the 3rd page if you drag the TabBar, but not if you drag the TabBarView.

How may I achieve this behavior?

---

**Edit:**

As stated by @Fethi, there's a similar question:
[Is it possible to swipe from an TabBarView content area to an adjacent PageView page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907970/is-it-possible-to-swipe-from-an-tabbarview-content-area-to-an-adjacent-pageview)

However, the question was not answered satisfactorily, as the solution given does not really "blend" the scroll, although the behavior is similar to what was described. It doesn't scroll naturally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is possible by using the `PageController.postion` attribute's `drag` method, which internally drags the `ScrollPosition` of the screen. This way, user can intuitively drag the pages like drag halfway and then leave or continue fully.

The idea is inspired from the other post to use the OverScrollNotification but add rather more step to continue intuitive dragging.

1. Collect the DragstartDetail when user starts scrolling.
2. Listen for OverScrollNotification and start the draging and at the same time update the drag using the `drag.update` with the DragUpdateDetails from OverscrollNotification method.
3. On ScrollEndNotification cancel the the drag.

To keep the idea simple I am pasting only build method of the Tabs page.

A fully working example is available in this [dart pad](https://dartpad.dev/abe26388e1f3a2ea0660fbd6089c6da5).

[image: demo]

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Local dragStartDetail.
    DragStartDetails dragStartDetails;
    // Current drag instance - should be instantiated on overscroll and updated alongside.
    Drag drag;
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TabBar(
          labelColor: Colors.green,
          indicatorColor: Colors.green,
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: <Tab>[
            const Tab(text: "Dark"),
            const Tab(text: "Normal"),
            const Tab(text: "Light"),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: NotificationListener(
            onNotification: (notification) {
              if (notification is ScrollStartNotification) {
                dragStartDetails = notification.dragDetails;
              }
              if (notification is OverscrollNotification) {
                drag = _pageController.position.drag(dragStartDetails, () {});
                drag.update(notification.dragDetails);
              }
              if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
                drag?.cancel();
              }
              return true;
            },
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(color: Colors.green[800]),
                Container(color: Colors.green),
                Container(color: Colors.green[200]),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

> **Old Answer**

The above might not handle some edge cases. If you need more control below code provides  the same result but you can handle `UserScrollNotification`. I am pasting this because, it might be useful for others who would like to know which direction the use is scrolling w.r.t the Axis of the `ScrollView`.

```dart
              if (notification is ScrollStartNotification) {
                dragStartDetails = notification.dragDetails;
              }

              if (notification is UserScrollNotification &&
                  notification.direction == ScrollDirection.forward &&
                  !_tabController.indexIsChanging &&
                  dragStartDetails != null &&
                  _tabController.index == 0) {
                _pageController.position.drag(dragStartDetails, () {});
              }

              // Simialrly Handle the last tab.
              if (notification is UserScrollNotification &&
                  notification.direction == ScrollDirection.reverse &&
                  !_tabController.indexIsChanging &&
                  dragStartDetails != null &&
                  _tabController.index == _tabController.length - 1) {
                _pageController.position.drag(dragStartDetails, () {});
              }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, this is great! I only have one concern... Why it will only scroll through pages on every second attempt? In the first it will not scroll and show the OverscrollIndicator instead...

Comment: Because its handled as part of OverScrolling for which the overscrolling has to occur. I felt  this is good because, user should be intimated of the end of the tabs which otherwise is probably not so intuitive. But the core idea is using the `drag` method to drag.Optionally you can try wrapping the last tab element with a gesture detector maybe to initiate the drag say like `onTapDown`.

Comment: check theis [gesture-disambiguation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures#gesture-disambiguation) section. Ultimately there will only one contender who wins the gesture. So you will have to override the tab`s gesture mechanism to have a smooth move, which I could say only be experimented on. :D

Comment: Do you have an idea how to do this? Every way I try needs to have a DragStartDetais, which is not available on tap down, only on drag, which causes the same behavior as unsing OverscrollNotification...

Comment: At this moment I don't. I will give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also experimenting here, if I get any results I tell you

Comment: I think I found a way. Give me some time.. I will perfect it and share.. :)

Comment: @MateusFelipe I have updated the answer. This is the best I could do.. Hope it helps you. You still might have to handle more cases. Perhaps you can ask your user for feedback and decide whether this smooth transition makes sense for them.  :D

Comment: Thanks, man. I got a similar behavior before, but yours is better. The only flaw that both mine and your solution have is that It doesn't work well with fast swipes. 
Maybe you would like to update your dartpad?

Comment: Done.. I would say it has to be played with a lot to handle the drag cancel very well..  Fast dragging is an issue not with our solution but, the gesture fight between pageview and tabview itself.. if they expose an api to actually explicitly stop page view from listening then it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

I have a different approach using **Listener** Widget and **TabView** physics as show below:

```
//PageView Widget
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   body: PageView(
    children: [
     Widge1()
     TabBarWidget(),
     Widget2()
    ]
   )
  )
}

//TabBar Widget
final _physycsNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
....
....
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
   children: [
    TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      //... other properties
    )
    Expanded(
      child: Listener(
       onPointerMove: (event) {
          final offset = event.delta.dx;
          final index = _tabController.index;

          //Check if we are in the first or last page of TabView and the notifier is false
          if(((offset > 0 && index == 0) || (offset < 0 && index == _categories.length - 1)) && !_physycsNotifier.value){
            _physycsNotifier.value = true;
          }
        },
        onPointerUp: (_) => _physycsNotifier.value = false;
        child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
          valueListenable: _physycsNotifier,
          builder: (_, value, __) {
            return TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              physics: value ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() : null,
              children: List.generate(_categories.length, (index) {
                return _CategoryTab(index: index);
              })
            );
          },
        ),
      )
    )
   ]
  )
}
```

this works fine if you set default physics for **PageView** and **TabView** (it means null) if you set other physisc like **BouncingScrollPhsysisc** there will be some bugs, but i think this is good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

so you want to scroll the page view to the left when you reach the end of tabs and the same goes to scrolling to the right when on the first tab, what i have been thinking about is manually swipe the page view when in those cases as follow:

`index` value should the index of page that comes before the tab bar page and after it.

```
pageController.animateToPage(index,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907970/is-it-possible-to-swipe-from-an-tabbarview-content-area-to-an-adjacent-pageview) is a complete code of what you are looking for, hopefully this helps!

Comment: Yes, the behavior is like this. I appreciate the link you referred. Although the behavior of the first answer is similar to what I described, I have the same concern as jibbers42 about "naturality". Miguel Ruivo said in the comments of his answer that it was a more complex behavior and suggested using nested TabBarView, but he didn't provided any concrete example, and jibbers42 said he couldn't achieve the behavior by himself

Comment: i didn't read the comments yesterday, well what are you looking as Miguel said is complex, i tried the nested tab bar but it doesn't seems to work, i recommend checking  this article for more help https://medium.com/flutterarsenal/build-a-nested-tabbar-in-flutter-7e0cae5cfc7

Comment: I already saw this article. I cloned the repo (https://github.com/IAmSarthakVerma/NestedTabBar-Flutter), but the app actually has the same behavior as the MRE I gave...

Comment: i'm sorry but that's all i can help with, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks... I got an almost ideal behavior by adapting Miguel's response from the other question... If I get to tune it, I'm going to post it as an answer here.

Comment: Great! Mr Abhilash Chandran has a solution